# Node (Express) doesn't start

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was trying out Express and trying to learn it, and I tried to start a server, but nothing's happening. I'm trying to access 127.0.0.1:8080 through Express, and I copied ALMOST all of the example (but not all). This is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => function() {
    let ip = req.ip
    console.log(ip);

    res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```

The app will log after starting `node server.js`, but nothing will appear at 127.0.0.1:8080. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You're mixing arrow function and function syntax. Use `app.get('/', (req, res) => {` (your code passed a function that returns a function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error using arrow functions, try the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let ip = req.ip
    console.log(ip);

    res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, just have to wait 4 minutes before marking it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

You have made a mistake in your endpoint callback function. `function` keyword is not used when arrow function syntax is used.

Either you use `function() {}`, or you use `() => {}` to write functions.

Correct code snippet would be:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let ip = req.ip
    console.log(ip);

    res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(port, ()=>console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`))
```